# MySQL statement for sum and percentage of column without using views

Tags: mysql

I'm successfully obtaining the sales per movie category using the [sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html) MySQL database. However, I haven't been able to calculate the percentages of the total sales using the same query.

Here is the query for the sum of sales for that:

```
select c.name as cat
     , sum(p.amount) sales 
  from payment p
  left join rental r 
    on p.rental_id = r.rental_id
  left join inventory i
    on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
  left join film f
  on i.film_id = f.film_id
  left join film_category fc
    on f.film_id = fc.film_id
  left join category c
    on fc.category_id = c.category_id
 group by cat
 order by sales desc;
```

I would need the sum of the sums of payments in total to divide that by the sum and get the percentage within the same table.

I want to start from here and obtain the percentages within the same table, whether it's using a subquery or any other way but NOT views. I cannot afford to create new views in my database.

Can this be done and if it can, how could I do it?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8? (Beware that `SUM()` is correct only if the query returns each row from `payment` once (I can't say if it's the case here, I'm not familiar with sakila).)

Comment: *"Beware that SUM() is correct only if the query returns each row from payment once"*  Topicstarter @ÁlvaroGonzález is talking about join multiplying aggregate results which can happen if you join on many-to-many or one-to_many relations when using aggregate functions..  you could use `sum(distinct payment.amount)` or `sum(payment.amount) / count(*)`  as easy fix to *"unmultiply"* that duplication.. But better is to use derived table approach table to aggregate  ... `from (select .., sum() ..) as a ..` or `[left/inner/right] join (select .., sum() ..) as a ..`

Comment: Unfortunately `DISTINCT` only solves that problem when you have IDs (e.g. `COUNT(DISTINT user.id) AS user_count`.

Comment: true forget to mention that .. @ÁlvaroGonzález `sum(distinct payment.amount)` requires deterministic (unique)  `payment.amount` values which is most likely not the case here.. Thats why you can better use a derived table approach table to aggregate no risk of getting wierd results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another (cross) join with an aggregate query that computes the total sales:

```
select 
    c.name as cat, 
    sum(p.amount) sales
    sum(p.amount)/total_sales as sales_ratio
from 
    payment p
    cross join (select sum(sales) total_sales from payment) t 
    left join rental r 
        on p.rental_id = r.rental_id
    left join inventory i 
        on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    left join film f 
        on i.film_id = f.film_id
    left join film_category 
        on f.film_id = fc.film_id
    left join category c 
        on fc.category_id = c.category_id
group by 
    c.name, 
    t.total_sales
order by 
    sales desc
;
```

Note: table aliases make the query shorter and easier to read. I modified your query to use aliases everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @GMB there were a couple of minor changes I had to make but after I figured it out it worked as expected.

Comment: Welcome @josescuderoh! Glad that it helped out.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL/8.0.2 you can use [window functions](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/):

```
SELECT category.name AS cat,
    SUM(payment.amount) AS sales,
    SUM(SUM(payment.amount)) OVER() AS total_sales,
    100 * SUM(payment.amount) / SUM(SUM(payment.amount)) OVER() AS percentage
FROM payment
LEFT JOIN rental ON payment.rental_id = rental.rental_id
LEFT JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
LEFT JOIN film ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
LEFT JOIN category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY sales DESC;
```

(I'm assuming that the JOINs do not produce duplicate rows for `payment`, I can't say whether it's the case.)

The official reference for the overall feature can be found at [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). This feature is available in most major DBMSs so learning it is a good investment.

Comment: no, I'm using an older version, 5.7.22. Over clauses are not working for me.

Comment: In older versions you need to resort to subqueries. For instance, you can join with a subquery that returns a single row with the appropriate grand total. That's what [GMB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58663395/13508) does.